# Data from the database won't show up

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I was trying to search through from my database using the Pet ID but data won't show up to my text fields also there's not even an error showing up it only says "Connection Success". I've double-checked to see if I'm wrong but with the statement, it should be working properly.

```
   try{

        String sql ="select * from pet_record where Pet ID=? ";
        
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,txt_petid.getText());
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        String add1 =rs.getString("Pet ID");
        txt_petnum.setText(add1);

        String add2 =rs.getString("Pet_Name");
        txt_pettag.setText(add2);

        String add3 =rs.getString("Pet_Age");
        txt_petage.setText(add3);

        String add4 =rs.getString("Pet_Gender");
        txt_petgender.setText(add4);

        String add5 =rs.getString("Pet_Weight");
        txt_petweight.setText(add5);

        String add6 =rs.getString("Pet_Guardian");
        txt_guardiancontact.setText(add6);

        String add7 =rs.getString("Guardian_Contact");
        txt_petguardian.setText(add7);

        String add8 =rs.getString("Date_Added");
        txt_dateadd.setText(add8);

       
        byte[] img = rs.getBytes("Pet_Image");
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img).getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl_img.getWidth(), lbl_img.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        lbl_img.setIcon(imageIcon);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    finally {

        try{

            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: 99% empty database or invalid query

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No error in console. it says User Program running and whenever I run the program it always  say "Connection Success".

Comment: The database got one data information and Pet ID # 1 but when I tried to type "1" from the text field(It has an event already with key released)  it won't show up.

Comment: Empty catch block. Put `e.printStackTrace();` in them, unless you want to ignore errors and remain clueless. You're not calling `rs.next()`.

Comment: @Kayaman There's an error popup wtf thank you so much man.  It says "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you very much. I already solved it. The data from the database showed up plus the image